# Have a class that only has main. Should I create an object and call obj.Main() or ClassObj.Main()?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a class - A - that has no methods, just the Main one.

In other class - B - I need to call that main. What's the best what to do it? From the point of resources used, time and power consuption and efficiency?

- Create an 'a' object from class A and execute a.Main() ?
- Execute A.Main() ?

Comment: are you talking about `public static void main(String... args){}`?

Answer (score 2):

There is never any reason to create an instance `a` just to invoke `a.Main()` if `Main` is a static method.

Just call `A.Main();`.

Comment: And If I have another class that has only one method. It's better that I delete that method and create a Main() and execute it in other side?

Comment: It really depends what you are doing. If you are just experimenting with the basics of the language I would make all your methods static and put them all in one class. At some stage you should aim to move away from static methods and learn about object oriented programming. So it really depends what stage you are at and what your code does.

Answer (score 1):

Execute A.Main() is best way, because a.Main() Java compiler transforms to A.Main() in any case

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do in main method. If the main method does something stateless (it only access the variables parse as a parameter and do something) then having it as a static method is the best approach. For example util methods in a library. If it alter some variables then those should be static in order to access from the static method and you need to think about the concurrency as well.

On the other hand static method cannot access non-static variables inside static method because non-static variables bound to the object we are creating using **new** key word. If we want alter the state of the object when we call main method then you should create an instance out of your A class and call main method.